# Python library to calculate surface area and volume of an arbirary polyhedron

Tags: python, geometry, polygon, computational-geometry

If I have an array of coordinates of the vertices of an arbitrary polyhedron, is there a library (preferably in python) that can calculate the surface area and volume of that polyhedron. The approach for these calculations appear [established](https://www.cs.uaf.edu/2015/spring/cs482/lecture/02_20_boundary/centroid_2013_nurnberg.pdf), but I could not find a library that has implemented this. More specifically, if I give the coordinates of a regular octahderon

```
arr1 = [[1,0,0],[-1,0,0],[0,1,0], [0,-1,0], [0,0,1], [0,0,-1]],
```

the code must return me a volume of

> 4/3 (formula: sqrt(2)*a^3/4)

Answer (score 3):

As long as the polyhedron is convex (which is my current interest), scipy has a class `ConvexHull` that can calculate both area and volume. For example, the volume for the above scenario can be calculated as follows

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
arr1 = [[1,0,0],[-1,0,0],[0,1,0], [0,-1,0], [0,0,1], [0,0,-1]]
arr1 = np.asarray(arr1)
volume = ConvexHull(arr1).volume
print volume
```

The above code produces the correct volume of *1.33333*